# Is the operator norm of a matrix equals the maximum of the same operator norm of the Jordan blocks?

Tags: linear-algebra

This considers any operator norm. Given a matrix $\bf A$, Let $\lambda({\bf A})$ be its spectrum, and ${\bf J}_\lambda$ be the Jordan block corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$. Do we have $\|{\bf A}\|=\max_{\lambda \in \lambda({\bf A})}\|{\bf J}_\lambda\|$ for any operator norm?

For 2-norm, it is true, see a previous post [Is the matrix norm of a matrix equal to the maximum of the norms of its Jordan block?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726960/is-the-matrix-norm-of-a-matrix-equal-to-the-maximum-of-the-norms-of-its-jordan-b).

If the claim does not hold for any operator norm, does it hold for some matrix norm other than 2-norm?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't think it's true for Frobenius norm. Or do you only care about induced norms? (Even so I also doubt it's true for $1$-norm, for the same reason that it's suspicious for the F-norm: Jordan blocks can be of much smaller sizes and much sparser.)

Comment: @Vim Thanks for comment, but Frobenius norm is not an operator norm. Yes, I also think it is not true for 1-norm or infinite norm. But I hope someone could give a more accurate characterization of the claim.

Answer (score 0):

This is false even for the $2$-norm, which I am guessing is the operator norm for operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its usual inner product. Consider for instance the operator on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual inner product, which, written with respect to an orthonormal basis, has the matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1000\\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The eigenvalues of this matrix are $1$ and $2$, but its operator norm is at least $1000$. The reason why the norm is not $2$ is that the decomposition into eigenspaces is not orthogonal.

Some orthogonality assumption is implicit in the answer that you cite, which is assuming (at least) that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equipped with an inner product that makes the generalized eigenspaces orthogonal.